# getSupportLoadManager() is deprecated

Tags: java, android

```
public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int swipeDir) {

                int id = (int) viewHolder.itemView.getTag();

                String stringId = Integer.toString(id);
                Uri uri = TaskContract.TaskEntry.CONTENT_URI;
                uri = uri.buildUpon().appendPath(stringId).build();

                getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);

                getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(TASK_LOADER_ID, null, MainActivity.this);

            }
        }).attachToRecyclerView(mRecyclerView);

        FloatingActionButton fabButton = findViewById(R.id.fab);

        fabButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent addTaskIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddTaskActivity.class);
                startActivity(addTaskIntent);
            }
        });

        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(TASK_LOADER_ID, null, this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(TASK_LOADER_ID, null, this);
    }
```

`getSupportLoadManager()` is deprecated. Anyone who has come across that error I would really use some help.

Answer (score 0):

Loaders have been deprecated as of API 28:

> **Loaders have been deprecated as of Android P (API 28).** The recommended
>   option for dealing with loading data while handling the Activity and
>   Fragment lifecycles is to use a combination of ViewModels and
>   LiveData. ViewModels survive configuration changes like Loaders but
>   with less boilerplate. LiveData provides a lifecycle-aware way of
>   loading data that you can reuse in multiple ViewModels.

For more info:

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders

Comment: Hi there, please cite the relevant parts of the link you posted directly in your answer, and provide the link for reference. Thanks, and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0):

Loaders have been deprecated as of Android P (API 28) as written in [Loaders](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders). You should change the `getSupportLoaderManager()` to `LoaderManager.getInstance(T)`.

[LoaderManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/loader/app/LoaderManager) is Static library support version of the framework's LoaderManager.